# contacts storage on android 2.3.5

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, contacts

Is there a way to have access to the file/s that list the contact details on an Android 2.3.5 phone? My contacts storage is growing up to many MBs, and I would like to be able to delete some of these contacts from the stored files with a scripted solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend you to use GUI of `Contacts` app for clearing contacts, but if you are really interested in it, this is the database used to store contact details: `/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db`. To alter anything inside it, you need root access and proper SQL queries.

The location of database may vary depending on device..